# Fatal error: Uncaught Error ( php mysql )

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am learning `php` oop with `mysql` and I am having trouble fixing this code.
I have checked it twice and also checked this platform to confirm.

```
    <?php 

require 'databasesclass.php';

$database = new Database();

$database->query('SELECT * FROM users');
$rows = $database->resultset();

print_r($rows);
```

**and my data base class are**

```
    <?php 


class Database{
    private $host = 'localhost:8889';
    private $user = 'root';
    private $pass = 'root';
    private $dbname = 'register';

    private $dbh;
    private $error;
    private $stmt;

    public function __construct(){
        // Set the DSN
        $dsn = 'mysql:host='. $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname . $this->user . $this->pass;
        // set options
        $options = array(

                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE    => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
            public function query($query){

                $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);

            }


            public function bind($pram, $value, $type = null){

                if (is_null($type)){
                    switch(true) {
                        case is_int($value):
                            $type = PDO::PRAM_INT;
                            break;
                        case is_bool($value):
                            $type = PDO::PRAM_BOOL;
                            break;  
                        case is_null($value):
                            $type = PDO::PRAM_NULL;
                            break;
                            default:
                            $type = PDO::PRAM_STR;  
                    }

                }

                $this->stmt->bindValue($parm, $value, $type);
            }

            public function execute(){
                 return $this->stmt->execute();
            }

            public function resultset(){
                $this->execute();
                return $this->stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }

}
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on
>   null in C:\MAMP\htdocs\Practice\databasesclass.php:31 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\MAMP\htdocs\Practice\index.php(7): Database->query('SELECT * FROM
>   u...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\Practice\databasesclass.php
>   on line 31

And the **Line 31** is:

```
$this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
```

Comment: I think your $dsn is not formed correctly (Your db is named "registerrootroot" ?) Which make PDO throw an exception.

Comment: dsn is working perfectly , i face the error when i type after the query function.

Comment: $this->dbh contains a PDO object ? From here, it looks like a null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to pass **$this->user** and  **$this->pass** into your **$dns** variable. Remove them from there.

So **$dns** variable will be

**from**

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname . $this->user . $this->pass;
```

**to**

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
```

Please check and let me if you see any error there.

Answer (score 0):

In the moment that you are executing the `$database->query('SELECT * FROM users')` the `$this->dbh` is null. You could check if it is an instance of PDO before do the `prepare`.